# Не посылаются куки CURL

Tags: curl

На сайте, котором авторизуюсь с помощью curl стоит лимит на количество авторизаций в сутки (10 раз).
Авторизацию прохожу нормально, с сохранением куков и мне открывается страница, которую видно только авторизированным пользователям.

Проблема в том, что если просто посылать куки, то показывается снова форма, что требуется залогинится. А это уже нежелательная трата попыток авторизации за день.

Вот так делаю:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; ru; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824 Firefox/3.5.3');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://turboliker.ru/index.php?page=cupon&tab=activate');
$html = curl_exec($curl); // должна появиться страница для авторизированного пользователя

echo $html;

curl_close($curl);
```

Как войти на эту страницу с моими же куками? Или проблема не в них?